# How to use php ternary operator in the parameter of a function?

Tags: php

I have a function,

```
abc(string $x, bool $y)
```

How can I use the ternary operator inside the function call expression? I tried this but gave

**unexpected T_RETURN error**

**Code:**

```
abc('Hello', return (1==1)?true:false);
```

Comment: The error mentions the return statement, not the ternary operator.

Comment: use this `abc('Hello',( 1 == 1 ? true : false ));`

Comment: remove `return` and it will work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In imperative languages like PHP, `return` is only used to return from a function. We call things like `return` statements, because they are things that one *states* in a function body.

On the other hand, things that have values or evaluate to values, like the number 2, or the expression 2 + 5 are called *expressions*.

You can think of `return` as a way to convert an expression (i.e., `"hello, world!"`) into an action (i.e., `return "hello,world!"`)

You can think of expressions like noun clauses (i.e., "a rock") and statements like actions (i.e., "give the rock to your boss").

In this case, PHP, like most imperative languages, expects you to only use expressions as arguments to functions.

Think about it -- what would it mean to pass an action as an argument to a function, or to add two actions together?

In the code you have, you want to call `abc` with the first argument set to `'Hello'` and the second set to the value of the expression `(1 == 1)?true:false`. In this case, you don't need the return statement because `(1==1)?true:false` is already an expression, so you can just do:

```
abc('Hello', (1==1)?true:false);
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the `return` there. Try replacing the line above with

```
abc('Hello',  (1==1)?true:false);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
  abc('Hello', $y = (1==1)?true:false);

  function abc($x, $y)
  {
    echo $x."  ".$y; 
  }
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
Hello 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `$y` is already supposed to be a boolean you can't need a ternary operator in your call. A ternary operator uses a boolean value to choose between two other values; if those other values are only `true` and `false` then the statement is redundant. You can simply write:

```
abc('Hello', 1==1);
```